# Android App crashing with the following error

Tags: java, xml, gradle, crash

```
09-10 16:24:41.486 21924-21924/com.parse.starter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.parse.starter, PID: 21924
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-gcBDXSCemV2D_lWzURBCRA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.parse.starter-gcBDXSCemV2D_lWzURBCRA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file
```

**this is my code: I think the error is in this part.**

```
*dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}*
```

Can you plaease help me in resolving the issue ; i am really stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq; when adding Google Maps to Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455001/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-android-gms-co)

Comment: I would guess this is a duplicate since you used `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0`. Use the sames version for both

Comment: Check with the version `12.0.1` that is common in both.

Answer (score 0):

Exception due to different versions of dependencies. Use same version for both.

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i am New to andriod and Java. Can you help upon what would be the same versions of the both?

Comment: As AxelH said try 12.0.1 for both.

Answer (score 0):

remove compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0' from the gradle file